# PowerBI fetch data with GET request with body

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to query an API where I have to pass username and password in the body. I have researched multiple methods but have not found any method which seems reasonable.

My query looks something like this:

```
URL: 
localhost:8080/v1/project

HEADERS: 
Content-Type: application/json

BODY:
{
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "password": "123456"
}
```

- In the docs I have found WebActions.Request, which is aparently disabled in most contexts (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/webaction-request).
- Web.Contents only allows a body in POST requests (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/web-contents).
- I'd rather not write a Python script to do it as it requires a Python installation.
- I tried this possible solution, but there was no success, as it would still perform a POST request: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/How-to-send-a-GET-method-with-content-data-with-M/m-p/943033/highlight/true#M32541

What reasonable way is there to achieve my goal to do a GET request with a body containing the credentials?

Comment: This is not possible unless you write your own custom connector, which does permit the use of `WebAction.Request` (although I'm not 100% sure it will actually handle the case of a `GET` with a body correctly, since that also depends on the underlying classes -- and `GET` requests with bodies are a grey area in the standard, so they're often blocked or transmuted). Fortunately custom connectors aren't that complicated to write (they're basically just M files you plonk in a specific directory), though there is still a bit of a learning curve.

Comment: Is it such an out of scope idea? What should be different on the backend that I could do an authenticated GET request?

Comment: It's a bit out there because the HTTP spec merely allows a `GET` request with a body on a technicality, it's not a well-defined operation. The obvious workaround would be to pass the parameters in the query string instead, or as the `Authorization` header. Using a `POST` request for the initial authentication is another option (this is how OAuth works, for example -- first a bearer token is obtained with a `POST`, then that is passed in the header for subsequent `GET` requests).